# Minimum security group rules for lambda to provision an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

This might be a very vague question, but I want to understand what should be the minimum security group rules for a lambda function that can provision an instance?
I tried a couple of security group rules but for me, only All traffic is working, in all other cases lambda failed to launch an instance mentioning that it's not able to connect to ec2 service. 
Just to make things a bit clearer, this lambda function starts an EC2 instance (using python boto) and then shuts it down after 5 minutes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What security group rules did you try that failed?

Comment: What do you mean by "security group rules for a lambda function"? Security Groups are used to control access to resources such as an Amazon EC2 instance. Lambda functions do not use Security Groups themselves, but the code that launches an instance can specify Security Groups that should be associated with the instance being launched. What do you mean by "launch an instance mentioning that it's not able to connect to ec2 service"? Can you show us some code?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi John, presumably Ash is running Lambda in VPC so needs to configure ENI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking what Security Group settings should be used **when an AWS Lambda function is associated with a VPC**, then the typical setting would be:

- Allow all Outbound to `0.0.0.0/0`

This allows the Lambda function to communicate with anything on the Internet, including the [Amazon EC2 endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

This is normally acceptable from a security perspective because the Lambda function is trusted (since you wrote the code!).

If the Lambda function is ***only* communicating with the EC2 endpoints** (and not interacting with resources inside the VPC), then you should actually **remove the VPC configuration for the function**. This will also remove the security group setting since the Lambda function would automatically gain the ability to communicate with the whole Internet.